# pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: $and/$or/$nor

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I tried coding like this:

```
input_filter = {"$and": []}

if not includeTestAccount:
    b = {"userLoginKey": {"$not": {"$regex": "^777"}}}
    input_filter["$and"].append(b)

if search_user_login_key is not None and search_user_login_key != "":
    b = {"userLoginKey":{"$regex":search_user_login_key}}
    input_filter["$and"].append(b)

if except_for_deletedaccount:
    b = {"deletedAt": {"$not": {"$regex": None}}}
    input_filter["$and"].append(b)

if except_for_deletedaccount:
    b = {"deletedAt": {"$not": {"$regex": None}}}
    input_filter["$and"].append(b)
```

but there was error in pymongo?:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: $and/$or/$nor must be a nonempty array,
full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': '$and/$or/$nor must be a nonempty array', 'code': 2, 'codeName': 'BadValue'}
```

Comment: Are you guaranteed that at least one of the `if` conditions will be `True`?

Comment: Yes, I guess so

Comment: Well, everytime your guess is wrong, the error will occur, yes?

Comment: Yes. everytime my guess is wrong, the error will occur.